# How to UNCOMMENT a line that contains a specific string using Sed?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

The lines in the file :

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2001 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2002 -j ACCEPT
```

to comment out let's say the line that contains

```
2001
```

i can simply run this SED command:

```
sed -i '/ 2001 /s/^/#/' file
```

but now how do i revert back ?

as in uncomment that same line ?

i tried

```
sed -i '/ 2001 /s/^//' file
```

that does not work.

Comment: `sed -i '/ 2001 /s/^#//' file` may be?

Comment: Why are you using this technique?  The standard technique would be to use one line in the script and make the year number into an argument to the script.  You could even default to, say, 2001 if no argument is provided (`${1:-2001}`), or use an environment variable (`${DEFAULT_YEAR:-2001}`), or both (`${1:-${DEFAULT_YEAR:-2001}}`).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try this `sed` command,

```
sed -i '/^#.* 2001 /s/^#//' file
```

Comment: why `.` that will remove the first character even if its not a comment ?

Comment: still needs to be fail proof. this answer needs corrections if it is to be chosen

Comment: You can tighten the line-matching regex to `/^#.* 2001 /`, but what you've got is strictly within the remit of the question.

Comment: Make it fail proof. must uncomment only if it is commented.

Comment: Oh, you're the op. So what's your actual file content?

Answer (score 144):

Yes, to comment line containing specific string with sed, simply do:

```
sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^/#/g' file
```

And to uncomment it:

```
sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#//g' file
```

In your case:

```
sed -i '/2001/s/^/#/g' file    (to comment out)
sed -i '/2001/s/^#//g' file    (to uncomment)
```

Option "g" at the end means global change. If you want to change only a single instance of pattern, just skip this.

Comment: add the `-e` argument for macOS and BSD

Comment: To avoid commenting multiple times and taking into account multiple leading `#`, use the following commands:

`sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#*/#/g' file        (to comment out)`
  
and

`sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#*//g' file          (to uncomment)`

Comment: Thanks jnlk and @louis-m. This solution is what worked best for me and accounting for multiple # characters works perfectly.

Comment: And if you want to make sure there is no whitespace at the start of line (e. g. in `# This is commented out` you can use `sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^#*\s*//g' file`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer IMHO, well explained.

Comment: best answer. thk

Comment: Why is it working? Where is `s/pattern/replacement/flags`???? :D

Comment: @smoothware this doesn't work if whitespace is before `#`. Instead use:
`sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^[#[:space:]]*/#/g' file` to comment out,
`sed -i '/<pattern>/s/^[#[:space:]]*//g' file` to uncomment

Comment: And use `sed -i_BKP-$(date -I) ...` to make a copy with a timestamp on the fly

Answer (score 6):

To complement [@Avinash Raj's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24889374/45375) with a **more generic**, **POSIX-compliant** solution.

- ***Toggles* commenting of lines** that match a **specifiable string** that must occur **as a separate word** anywhere on the line.
- The **comment character** (string) is also **specifiable**.

Note that the **solution is `awk`-based**, because a robust *portable* solution with `sed` is virtually impossible due to the limitations of POSIX' *basic* regular expressions.

```
awk -v commentId='#' -v word='2001' '
  $0 ~ "(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])" word "($|[[:punct:][:space:]])" { 
    if (match($0, "^[[:space:]]*" commentId))
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    else
      $0 = commentId $0
  } 
  { print }
  ' file > tmpfile.$$ && mv tmpfile.$$ file
```

- `(^|[[:punct:][:space:]])` and `($|[[:punct:][:space:]])` are the POSIX extended regex equivalents of the `\<` and `\>` word-boundary assertions known from other regex dialects.
- Whitespace *after* the comment char is preserved, but not before it.
- When prepending the comment char to a line, it is directly prepended, without whitespace.
- Thus, if you only toggle comments with *this* solution, all whitespace is preserved.
- POSIX `awk` doesn't offer in-place updating (neither does POSIX `sed`, incidentally), hence the output is first captured in a temporary file and that file then replaces the original on success.

Answer (score 2):

Quick example of how to comment and uncomment a line in a file.

Sample file :

```
umask 027
TMOUT=600
```

Lets now backup the file (just for laughs) and comment out and un comment:

```
# backup file (because we should always do this)
cp /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc.$(date '+%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S')

# original: TMOUT=600   , result :# TMOUT=600
sed -i '/[^#]/ s/\(^TMOUT=600.*$\)/#\ \1/' /etc/bash.bashrc

# original # TMOUT=600   ,result :TMOUT=600
sed -i '/^#.*TMOUT=600.*$/s/^#\ //' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac, which doesn't support standard sed parameters, this would remove the hashtag

```
sed -i "" "/.*#.*d\/docker-php-ext-xdebug\.ini.*/s/^#//g" docker-compose.yml
```