# Comment out/Comment in lines with sed

Tags: linux, sed

In my nginx configuration file I have the following lines:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

Now, I would like to comment out/uncomment the two lines programmatically:

```
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

So I thought about `sed` and found this post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27355109

Unfortunately I could not get it work. Perhaps there're problems with escapting the chars. Could someone help?

Comment: *"... I could not get it work ..."* is not a good problem statement. It lacks both the code you are using and the error you are encountering.

Comment: do you want to comment them out based on their content on based on their location relative to the surrounding lines or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comment these lines out, use command

```sh
sed \
    -e 's|auth_basic "Restricted Content";|# \0|' \
    -e 's|auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;|# \0|' \
    your_file
```

To uncomment, use this:

```sh
sed \
    -e 's|# \(auth_basic "Restricted Content";\)|\1|' \
    -e 's|# \(auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;\)|\1|' \
    your_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!